# Multiple sets of rules to convert .cpp files into .o files in make

Tags: makefile

Say I have the following makefile:

```
SRC = trav.cpp
LSRC = node.cpp tree.cpp
LIB = lib/libvtree.so

OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(SRC))
LOBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,obj/%.o,$(LSRC))


$(LOBJS) : $(LSRC)
      $(CC) -fPIC -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJS) : $(SRC)
      $(CC) -o $@ -c $<

$(LIB) : $(LOBJS)
      $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(LOBJS) $^

trav.exe: $(LOBJS) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
      $(CC) -o $@ $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -Llib libvtree -lstdc++
```

Basically, I'm trying to compile 2 sets of cpp files: $(LSRC) into a library and $(SRC) into an executable that links into that library.

But when I try to 'make' it, I get the following error:

```
gcc -fPIC -o obj/node.o -g -DMEMPOOL -c src/node.cpp
gcc -fPIC -o obj/tree.o -g -DMEMPOOL -c src/node.cpp
```

It keeps trying to compile node.cpp into both the .o files.

Is there a way in make to specify separate rules for separate sets of files, without splitting up
the diirectory tree and using a recursive make.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out pattern rules. http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These rules probably aren't doing what you think they are:

```
$(LOBJS) : $(LSRC)
      $(CC) -fPIC -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJS) : $(SRC)
      $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

`$<` expands to the *first* prerequisite of the rule, which just means whichever source file is first in the `$(SRC)` list.  You don't want that, and in fact it's probably a misrepresentation of the dependencies - `node.o` doesn't depend on `tree.cpp`, right?

To make it work, you want them to be pattern rules, to match up a specific object with a specific source file.

```
$(LOBJS) : obj/%.o : %.cpp
      $(CC) -fPIC -o $@ -c $<

$(OBJS) : obj/%.o : %.cpp
      $(CC) -o $@ -c $<
```

You might need a `src/` in there too,  but I don't see where that came from in your original file.  The `-g -DMEMPOOL` too, for that matter.

Editorial note: it would be idiomatic to use `CXX` rather than `CC` since you have a C++ program.